# SQL Script to replace all FK values based on the dependencies? Is it even possible?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I want to merge two users(ie Need to delete a user. Before that update all the references of that user with another user). 
I want to replace all references of the user to deleted with the new user id.
Is it possible to do that using any sql script by getting the dependencies of that User Table?

**[Updated]**
I am looking for a script that automatically identify the dependencies and swap the userid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, identifying table's dependencies (foreign key constraints) is possible programmatically.
What you need are the [sys-Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx).

In particular you need:

- sys.all_objects (to get the tables' names)
- sys.foreign_key_columns (to get the foreign keys you are looking for)
- sys.columns (to get the names of the columns in question)

With that in mind

```
SELECT
        ReferencedTable.name AS ReferencedTableName,
        ReferencedColumn.name AS ReferencedColumnName,
        DependingTable.name AS DependingTableName,
        DependingColumn.name AS DependingColumnName
    FROM sys.all_objects AS DependingTable
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS ForeignKeys
        ON DependingTable.object_id = ForeignKeys.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS ReferencedTable
        ON ForeignKeys.referenced_object_id = ReferencedTable.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS DependingColumn
        ON ForeignKeys.parent_object_id = DependingColumn.object_id AND ForeignKeys.parent_column_id = DependingColumn.column_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS ReferencedColumn
        ON ForeignKeys.referenced_object_id = ReferencedColumn.object_id AND ForeignKeys.referenced_column_id = ReferencedColumn.column_id
    WHERE ReferencedTable.name = 'UserTable'
```

will give you a result set, each row representing one existing foreign key, with your referenced table name, the referenced column name and of course the names of the depending (referencing) table and its column. Now we can take this a small step further:

Given that you know what user id is going to be deleted and which id shall serve as substitute you can let that last query just generate update statements for you, the following code does just that and on top of that uses a cursor to execute those statements right away (you just need to set `@tableName`, `@sourceValue` and `@targetValue`):

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'UserTable'
DECLARE @sourceValue INT = 3
DECLARE @targetValue INT = 1

DECLARE @sqlStatements TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), cmdTxt NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT @sqlStatements (cmdTxt)
    SELECT
            'UPDATE ' + DependingTable.name + ' SET ' + DependingColumn.name + ' = ' + CAST(@targetValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) +
            ' WHERE ' + DependingColumn.name + ' = ' + CAST(@sourceValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM sys.all_objects AS DependingTable
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS ForeignKeys
            ON DependingTable.object_id = ForeignKeys.parent_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS ReferencedTable
            ON ForeignKeys.referenced_object_id = ReferencedTable.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns AS DependingColumn
            ON ForeignKeys.parent_object_id = DependingColumn.object_id AND ForeignKeys.parent_column_id = DependingColumn.column_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns AS ReferencedColumn
            ON ForeignKeys.referenced_object_id = ReferencedColumn.object_id AND ForeignKeys.referenced_column_id = ReferencedColumn.column_id
        WHERE ReferencedTable.name = @tableName

DECLARE @currentCmd NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cmd_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT cmdTxt FROM @sqlStatements ORDER BY ID ASC

OPEN cmd_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cmd_cursor 
INTO @currentCmd

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @currentCmd

    FETCH NEXT FROM cmd_cursor 
    INTO @currentCmd
END 
CLOSE cmd_cursor;
DEALLOCATE cmd_cursor;
```

*You probably should encapsulate this whole thing in a transaction and do some comforting select statements at the end that show you that you did not break anything, before finally commiting the changes.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you can first create a new user and after inserting , update the reference based on condition.

like

```
declare @newUserid int , @olduserid
insert user values (colval1, colval2,..)

select @newUserid = @@identity

update tablename set userid = @newUserid where userid = @olduserid
```

if multiple user, then create a dynamic query for update statement.

```
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Set @query = 'update tablename set userid = ' + @newUserid + ' where userid in ( ' + @olduserid + ')'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

At the end you can delete the user(s).

**Update**
For auto-mated process, you use Sql Jobs or use trigger. You can schedule Sqljob, while trigger is fired on table whenever insert,update,delete happened.

So drawback of trigger is performance point of view, while for sql-job, you need sqlagent feature, which is available in sqlserver enterprice edition or equilant, express edition does not have Sqlagent.

What I suggest, whenever you insert or update, you can use or say call another procedure which update the record as per current schenerio.

You are not given us any schenerio i.e. if userid = 1 or usertype = 'guest' update, then change the data etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called `Cascade Update` in `SQL SERVER`. The `ON UPDATE CASCADE` option Specifies that if an attempt is made to update a key value in a row, where the key value is referenced by foreign keys in existing rows in other tables, all of the foreign key values are also updated to the new value specified for the key. If cascading referential actions have also been defined on the target tables, the specified cascading actions are also taken for the key values updated in those tables

check **[here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119(v=sql.80).aspx)** for more info

```
ALTER TABLE childtablename
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_name FOREIGN KEY(childcolumn) REFERENCES parenttable (parentcolumn) ON  UPDATE  CASCADE
```